# Can I define terraform cloud credentials in environment variables instead of .terraformrc file?

Tags: terraform

I understand that I need to define terraform cloud credentials in the  .terraformrc file, as explained here:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/cli-config.html#credentials-1

[image]

Is there any way not to use the .terraformrc file and set the credential and token in environment variables?

PS:

Just a side question, do we have a StackOverflow tag for Terraform Enterprise or Cloud?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is both yes and no.

If the question is authenticating the TFE provider with environment variables, then the answer is yes. That change was made in [this PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-tfe/pull/78) to enable `TFE_TOKEN` and `TFE_HOSTNAME` for authenticating the TFE provider as an alternative to the Terraform CLI config file. You can then interact with your TFE/Terraform Cloud with that provider and authenticating with environment variables.

If the question is authenticating TFE interactions via the Terraform CLI with environment variables, then the answer is no. TFE authentication is not among the [listed environment variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html) for the Terraform CLI. I have also verified in a quick test that the provider authentication environment variables do not similarly function for the CLI. For that, you must use a `terraform.rc`, `.terraformrc`, or `credentials.tfrc.json`.

Comment: Thank you for help. Considering that CLI is using TFE provider defined in scripts, is it safe to assume that when terraform.rc is missing, the TFE provider in scripts takes over and reads the environment variable TFE_TOKEN?

Comment: Yes: the provider will authenticate with the environment variable in the absence of a CLI configuration file. The CLI will still be unable to authenticate though.

Answer (score 1):

The lookup of credentials in the CLI configuration is the default way Terraform handles credentials, but you can override that behavior by configuring a [credentials helper](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/cli-config.html#credentials-helpers), which is an external program Terraform will run in order to obtain credentials, instead of consulting the configuration files directly.

Credentials helpers are arbitrary programs that happen to support a particular protocol over their stdin/stdout, and so they can in principle do anything, including checking environment variables. I previously wrote [`terraform-credentials-env`](https://github.com/apparentlymart/terraform-credentials-env) as a credentials helper which does exactly that, and so configuring that helper might be sufficient to get what you needed here, or if not you could potentially use it as an example to [write your own credentials helper](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/credentials-helpers.html).

Note that Terraform's model of credentials is host-oriented rather than service-oriented, so in setting this up we're configuring Terraform to use the given credentials for all [services](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/remote-service-discovery.html) on `app.terraform.io`. That includes both the Terraform Cloud/Enterprise-specific `remote` backend *and* the other services that Terraform Cloud is just one implementation of, like the module registry protocol.